# Introduction to Proper Forcing Reference

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

What is a good introduction to proper forcing? I am aware of Shelah *Proper and Improper Forcing*, but I heard this book may be somewhat challenging to read. There is also Devlin's *The Yorkshiremen's Guide to Proper Forcing* and Baumsgartner's *Applications of the Proper Forcing Axiom*.

Are any of the above good introductions to proper forcing? Are there other surveys in proper forcing that I did not list above that may work better as an introduction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good stretch for understanding proper forcing a little bit.

Start with Jech *Multiple Forcing*, he covers the basics there. Then re-read the same material in Abraham's *Handook of Set Theory* chapter, aptly named Proper Forcing.

Being his M.Sc. student, I had the pleasure of having him explain some things in person. So I can only recommend that you buy a plane ticket to Israel and meet with him. But since it seems a bit too much to suggest, here is some insight that I took from him.

The definition of proper forcing seems very unnatural at first (which is why I suggested Jech, which uses a much simpler definition), but after doing a few examples - in particular Baumgartner's forcing which adds a club with finite conditions - the definition using countable submodels and master conditions becomes much clearer.

Which is why I suggested above to begin with Jech, then re-learn most of the things there from Abraham's chapter (after having a rudimentary understanding of *a* definition of proper forcing it becomes easier).

Comment: I would agree that Abraham's chapter is very good (at least the few sections that I have read). Additionally, Kunen added some material on proper forcing to the new edition of his book, but that will probably be too little for any serious study.

Comment: I haven't seen Kunen's new book, so I can't comment about that.

Comment: If he's already going to buy a plane ticket to Israel, he should first meet the guy who invented proper forcing. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Asaf's recommendations, you should also check Martin Goldstern's "Tools for your forcing construction": http://info.tuwien.ac.at/goldstern/papers/tools.ps

Once you're familiar with the basics of proper forcing, I recommend checking the wonderful book of Bartoszynski and Judah for some applications in the set theory of the reals (in particular, check chapter 6 for some nice preservation theorems).